# tomcat run configurations in intellij IDEA

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

hi i use intellij IDEA to run my servlet programs using tomcat, intellij provides several run configurations as follow: [image]

could you tell me what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty self explanatory aren't they ? Resources, static resources anything that isn;t java.
Classes and resources, everything.

Worth noting, you can use the second in the list and use debug mode to get hot deploy working(with an expanded war if using wars).  Set to update on lose focus for a nice smooth debugging process.

(your jsps, servlets, js, html (or equivalents) will all be updated to the latest editted/compiled version when you use a different app to intellij, ie switch to your browser)

Comment: so you mean that (update resource) just updates the static stuff like the files in resources folder but not the servlet codes.and the second option updates the servlet codes too the last option redeploy all the files to server and restarts the server but what about the third option?

Comment: redeploy ? it redeploys the whole artifact ... probably a war file, or expanded war file.

Comment: sorry to ask again, So restart Re Deploys and also restarts the server? and what about (update classes and resources)? it dosen`t redeploy the war file but updates the files which are already on the server?

Comment: No redeploy doesn't restart the server. And yes update doesn't redeploy. I generally use update classes and resources, for everyday dev.

Comment: no i mean restart=redeploy war files+restart the server.

Comment: just one last piece of question ;D if (update classes and resources) changes files on the server why do we need deploy option?

Comment: becuase you want to debug something that is dependent on deloyment (eg, @PostConstruct in spring)